# Button not working on Pjax Reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, pjax

I am using Yii2 php framework and my page looks like this:

[image]

Based on the photo, when I click one of the radio buttons, for example "Pending", the `GridView` would only display all pending reimbursements.

The problem is that, in the Action column, the buttons don't work anymore. As you can see there are "Approve" and "Disapprove" buttons. When I click the Approve button, it alerts a message "Are you sure you want to approve reimbursement?" and when I click okay, nothing happens. Everything remains the same.

Same goes when only Approved/Disapproved statuses are displayed where their "Approve" and "Disapproved" buttons won't become disabled anymore, they instead become clickable.

**PHP**
Here is my Actions column in `GridView` in my `index.php` view:

```
[
    'label' => 'Action',
    'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        if($model->status == "Pending"){
            return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2'])
            .'&nbsp'
            .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Approve', ['value' =>  $model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-responsive', 'onclick'=>'approve(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Approve', 'data' => [ 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to approve this reimbursement?', 'method' => 'post', ]])
            .'&nbsp'
            .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Disapprove', ['value' =>  $model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-responsive', 'onclick'=>'disapprove(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Disapprove', 'data' => [ 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to disapprove this reimbursement?', 'method' => 'post', ]]);
        }else{
            return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2'])
            .'&nbsp'
            .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Approve', ['value' =>  $model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-responsive disable', 'onclick'=>'approve(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Approve', 'data' => [ 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to approve this reimbursement?', 'method' => 'post', ]])
            .'&nbsp'
            .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Disapprove', ['value' =>  $model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-responsive disable', 'onclick'=>'disapprove(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Disapprove', 'data' => [ 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to disapprove this reimbursement?', 'method' => 'post', ]]);
        }
     }
]
```

This `GridView` is placed inside 
`<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'reimbursements', 'enablePushState' => false,]); ?>` and `<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>` tags.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
    $('.disable').attr('disabled','disabled'); 

    $('input[type=radio]').prop('name', 'filter');
    var showAll = $('input[name=filter]').val();
    if(showAll == "Show All") {
        $('#reimbursements').addClass('showAll');
    }
    $('.showAll').load();
    function load(){
        $('.showAll').load();
    }

    $('#filter .radio > label').on('click', function(e) {
        var input = $('input', e.target);
        var sortby = input.val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=reimbursement/filter',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {sortby: sortby},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('.disable').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#reimbursements .table-responsive.all', fragment: '#reimbursements .table-responsive.all'});
                $('.disable').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        $('.disable').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    });

    $('.disable').attr('disabled','disabled'); 

    function approve(id){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=reimbursement/approve',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {id : id},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#reimbursement_grid'});
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }

    function disapprove(id){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=reimbursement/disapprove',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {id : id},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#reimbursement_grid'});
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("error");
            }
        });    
    }
    $('.disable').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
})
```

Hope someone could be able to tell me why the buttons are not functioning anymore and could help me how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's my updated code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive all">
    <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'reimbursement_grid']); ?>
        <?php echo $this->render('_index', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider ]); ?>
    <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
//$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('name', 'filter');
    var showAll = $('input[name=filter]').val();
    if(showAll == "Show All") {
        $('#reimbursements').addClass('showAll');
    }
    $('.showAll').load();
    function load(){
        $('.showAll').load();
    }

    $('#filter .radio > label').on('click', function(e) {
        var input = $('input', e.target);
        var sortby = input.val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=reimbursement/filter',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {sortby: sortby},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#reimbursement_grid', fragment: '#reimbursement_grid'});
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });

    $('.disable').prop('disabled','disabled');     
});

function approve(id){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=reimbursement/approve',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id : id},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#reimbursement_grid'});
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}

function disapprove(id){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=reimbursement/disapprove',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id : id},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#reimbursement_grid'});
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("error");
        }
    });    
}
</script>
```

I put the functions `approve` and `disapprove` outside `$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){...})` and changed the `container` and `fragment` of `pjax.reload` to `#reimbursement_grid`.

Hope this would also help anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**HERE IS THE WORKING SOLUTION**

```
$(document).on("ready pjax:success", function () {
    alert("Write your code here...."); 
});
```